# Two Toolbars, Only the second one should collapse on scroll in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, scroll, toolbar

I have the following code inside a CoordinatorLayout. What this code basically does is that it has two toolbars on top of one another [See Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU17E.jpg). What I plan to achieve is that when users scroll down, only the second toolbar collapses.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_home_appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_filters"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/category"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    style="@style/FlatButton"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_category_btn"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/filter"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_filter_btn"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    style="@style/FlatButton"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>



        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: It has been some time, but did you actually succeed in getting the desired result? If you did, would be awesome if you could share your xml code. I'm trying to achieve the same, without success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CollapsingToolbar layout to achieve this. Its one of the material design UI component they have released when you want to collapse any view over scroll. Follow the below link to understand how it works,

https://www.journaldev.com/13927/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example

use toolbar instead of imageview in the example.