# CollapsingToolbar with second toolbar instead of ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am trying to create an app with two toolbars on top and a specific collapsing/expanding behaviour on scrolling. See the mockup to get a deeper understanding of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Mockup]

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730697/two-toolbars-only-the-second-one-should-collapse-on-scroll-in-coordinatorlayout) StackOverflow question that is trying to achieve for about the same, and the response is hinting towards using a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and just using another `<Toolbar />` instead of the usual `<ImageView />`, but I tried around and could not get any close to the desired result.

My current xml layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="01/01/1999"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="Title"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/placeholder"/>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the corresponding activity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

I am using a `NoActionBar` theme. If I run this configuration, there is just one `Toolbar` displayed, nothing can be seen from the second `Toolbar` or the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Huge thanks to anyone who is trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the `CoordinatorLayout` into a another `ViewGroup` and add the main `Toolbar` into this new root layout instead. This will avoid the confusion of the `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` to the main toolbar.

So now the entire layout hierarchy would be:

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar>  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< main toolbar
    
    <CoordinatorLayout>
        <AppBarLayout>
            <CollapsingToolbarLayout> 
                <Toolbar>  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< second toolbar
        <NestedScrollView>
            <TextView>
```

Then to fix the collapsing behavior like you want you need to change the scrolling flags of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to `"scroll|enterAlways"` instead of `"scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"`. This will make the toolBar **always enter** off the top screen.

And build the layout of the second `Toolbar` with a normal `ViewGroup` inside of it; here I'm using `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:title="Title"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/black" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbar_layout">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#F2ECF6"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="32dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/left_arrow"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_ios_24"
                            app:tint="@color/black" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/right_arrow"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_forward_ios_24"
                            app:tint="@color/black" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="01/01/1999"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="22sp"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_arrow"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left_arrow"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/placeholder"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, this was the answer I was looking for. Note that I left away the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, as it seems to have no purpose in this case. The shadow of the appbar at scrolling can be achieved by using `liftOnScroll="true"` on the `AppBarLayout`. Also I needed `fillViewPort="true"` on the root `ConstraintLayout`.